# Conditional formatting comparing previous cell value in column while skipping blanks

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets I have columns of numeric values and I would like to style a decrease in value as red. I have done so with a simple formula comparing the previous cell's value, but I cannot figure out how to get the *last entered value* in the column, skipping any blank cells.

```
|   |    A    |
|---|---------|
| 1 | Numbers |
|---|---------|
| 2 |      100|
| 3 |       75| // Red (decrease from 100)
| 4 |       90|
| 5 |         |
| 6 |       70| // Red (decrease from 90)
| 7 |       71|
| 8 |         | 
| 9 |       68| // Red (decrease from 71)
|10 |       65| // Red (decrease from 68)
```

My simple formula for `A2:A` is `=AND(A1<>"",A2<A1)` which works fine for `A3` and `A10`. What I need is that last `A1` in my formula to actually be the last valid cell value, no just the previous.

Answer (score 0):

Please select ColumnA from A2 to wherever suits and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., **Custom formula is** enter:

```
=and(A2<>"",A2<vlookup(1E+100,A$1:A1,1,1))
```

and for Formatting style choose red, <kbd>Done</kbd>.